# Make an image in a table cell into a link

Tags: hyperlink, visual-studio-2013, e-commerce

I have created an e-commerce website and am using a label to display the products from my sql database, the image it shows of these products are not hyperlinks, but this is what I need them to be, I think I have written the right code but I have a "parentControl" error, could someone help plz?

Below is also a link to show you visually what is being asked. REMEMBER the picture is just an image, but needs to be a hyperlink!

```
           private void FillPage()
    {
        ArrayList teesList = new ArrayList();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            teesList = ConnectionClass.GetTeesBySize("%");
        }
        else
        {
            teesList = ConnectionClass.GetTeesBySize(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
        link.NavigateUrl = "http://google.com";

        parentControl.Controls.Add(link);

        foreach (Tees tees in teesList)

        {
            sb.Append(string.Format(@"<table class='TeesTable'>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan='1' width='150px'><img runat='server' src='{6}' /</th>
                    <th width='50px'>Name: </th>
                    <td>{0}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Size:</th>
                    <td>{1}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Price:</th>
                    <td>{2}</td>
                </tr>



            </table>",
                     tees.name, tees.size, tees.price, tees.id, tees.id, tees.id, tees.image));
            LblOutput.Text = sb.ToString();
```

(https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/CompetitiveStreakTemplate/Pic.png?_subject_uid=9403629&w=AAD63dzqPQcNMNSU0OwbVBrGjNGFvtt7VWJ6DKwlu4UoPw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your `<img>` tag properly and wrap it in a `<a>` to make it a hyperlink. Also use `<td>` instead of `<th>` for data rows and not headers.

Something a bit more like:

`<td rowspan='1' width='150px'>
    <a href='{0}.aspx'>
        <img runat='server' src='{6}' />
    </a>
 </td>`

You should probably also tidy up the rest of the code appended to your table, checking what is a header or data, and using a `<tbody>` tag inside the `<table>`

Edit: looking closer it seems as though you aren't creating the table properly in the first place, change this chunk of your code to do the loop properly:

```
parentControl.Controls.Add(link);

sb.Append("<table class='TeesTable'><tbody>");

foreach (Tees tees in teesList)
{
    sb.Append(string.Format(@"
            <tr>
                <td rowspan='1' width='150px'>
                    <a href='{0}.aspx'>
                        <img runat='server' src='{6}' />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td width='50px'>Name: </td>
                <td>{0}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Size:</td>
                <td colspan='2'>{1}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Price:</td>
                <td colspan='2'>{2}</td>
            </tr>",

         tees.name, tees.size, tees.price, tees.id, tees.id, tees.id, tees.image));
    }

    sb.Append("</tbody></table>");

    LblOutput.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you VERY Much!, they are now hyperlinks!, but now the only problem is that each product lead to the same page, how would I give each product a different url?

Comment: Do you store the url's in your Tees object?

Comment: The pages are just stored in my project as "name.aspx".

Comment: Updated answer, hopefully your `name`s are all html friendly

Comment: Yeah I just added my Homepage into the code and my tshirts are now all linking to my homepage, but obviously I need to be able to add different paths for each product.

Comment: Did you see the update? the links should go to *name*.aspx for each item now

Comment: Yeah, I see your update but thats still sends every product clicked to the same destination, when each product needs its own

Comment: Do all your products have a different name in the name column?

Comment: OH wow, I just noticed something interesting, when I click each Item it is trying to the page thats has the same name as that particular product, so now if I create that page it should work.

Comment: I just updated my answer again so you will be creating one big table instead of a bunch of little ones...

Comment: I dont know how to thank you, do you how long I have been trying to figure this out, I even emailed my tutor and supervisor and they did not help one bit, I finally have it working. BUT! one but, I cannot add the pages inside folders and I have a lot of products

Comment: You could do that by having a `tees.folder` property which stores the folder you keep the page in then you could do something like `a href='{7}/{0}.aspx'` and put `tees.folder` on the end of the `string.format` expression

Comment: Yeah I just actually worked that out, my code now looks like this 
<a href='Products/Tshirts/{0}.aspx'>

Like I said before you are actually a life saver, thank you very much, I really appreciate your help, seriously.

Comment: Yeah, its basically the last part of my site functionality I needed to work and now it is!, and sorry :) how do I accept your answer?

Comment: click the tick symbol near the top left of my answer